# Confidence interval disappears in ggplot2 using coord_cartesian

Tags: r, ggplot2

Limiting the x range by `coord_cartesian` makes the confidence interval created by `stat_smooth` disappear.

I noticed it happens with R 4.1.0 but not with R 4.0.2.
The ggplot2 version I used was 3.3.5.

The first plot shows the confidence interval as a shade. The second plot should show the same confidence interval in the specified range. But with R 4.1.0, the shade disappear.
Any one experiencing it?

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth()

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(3, 4))
```

Comment: This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4498) seems pretty similar as the CI ribbon from `stat_smooth()` is related to the ribbon geom.

Comment: can't reproduce with r-devel on Ubuntu, but GitHub issues suggests it's Windows (and maybe RStudio?) specific. From the thread, "Switching to ragg in Rstudio fixed the issue for both base and ggplot": from the ragg README file, "ragg can be used as the graphic back-end to the RStudio device (for RStudio >= 1.4) by choosing AGG as the backend in the graphics pane in general options (see screenshot)"

Comment: Yes, the geom_ribbon issue seems the same issue. The issue is on Windows 10 64bit. It also happens regardless of RStudio. So the situation is almost identical. Selecting AGG as the backend SOLVED the problem.  :)

Answer (score 5):

*The comments solved the problem. I summarize them as an answer. Thanks.*

The issue is the R 4.1.0 problem on Windows.
See the `ggplot2` issue [Problem with geom_ribbon and alpha combined with coord-cartesian in R 4.1.0 on Windows](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4498).

The remedy is using ragg as a graphic backend. If you are using RStudio >= 1.4, change the graphic backend to AGG by going to General option -> General -> Graphics.